# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeContacts.default.getAll')

Tags: android, react-native, hyperlink, expo, react-native-contacts

I am trying du use react-native-contacts with a react-native app made with Expo, but I have this error message :

`undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeContacts.default.getAll')`

Here is the code I use :

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Modal,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ImageBackground,
  TextInput,
  Picker,
  PermissionsAndroid
} from 'react-native';
import { WebBrowser } from 'expo';
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText'; 


  Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
    if (err === 'denied'){
      // error
    } else {
      // contacts returned in Array
    }
  })
```

I tried to follow all he steps for the installation in this page for the android part :
https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts#getting-started

But I don't find where I can do this part :
I don't know where I can find this file : android/settings.gradle

By the way I tried this command "react-native link" in my app directory and nothing changed.

```
Android
In android/settings.gradle
...
include ':react-native-contacts'
project(':react-native-contacts').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-contacts/android')
In android/app/build.gradle
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
}
```

Has anyone had this kind of problem ?
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are developing your app with Expo. Some of independent libraries doesn't work well with Expo. I have two suggestions for you.

1. If you want to keep using react-native-contacts, you need to eject your app from Expo
2. Or directly use Expo's contacts api, You can find the details in this link [Expo's Contacts](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/contacts/) I would do this which is less work for you to do and solve your problem

   ```
   import { Contacts } from 'expo';

   const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
       fields: [Contacts.Fields.Emails],
   });

   if (data.length > 0) {
       const contact = data[0];
       console.log(contact);
   }
   ```

You can find same issue created in react-native-contacts github page . [Issue](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts/issues/220#issuecomment-403137614)

Comment: Thanks a lot !
That's prettay anoying not to be able to use other librairies :-/
Do you know a way to ski expo ?

Comment: You need to eject your expo project by `expo eject` . I wouldnt recommend you to eject if you dont need to write native codes.  You can read here in details. https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/expokit/expokit/

Comment: Thanks !
I ll go with expo for the moment !
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

## July 2021 update

The `Contacts` module has been moved from the core `expo` package to `expo-contacts` (see [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/contacts/)).

### Example:

```
import * as Contacts from 'expo-contacts';

const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();

if (status === 'granted') {
  const { data: contacts } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync();

  console.log('Retrieved contacts!', contacts);
}
```